# JointJS cell:mouseout triggers on foreignObject? update custom element contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jointjs

I'm attempting to make an element that gets larger when it's clicked on and then shows a foreignObject form.

http://jsfiddle.net/zb88ru0s/11/

Problems:

1) I can't figure out how to change the `customForm` element into the form.  It throws a `Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name` when I try:

```
cellView.model.attr('customForm', '<foreignObject><form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">First Name: <input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="first_name" type="text"></input></form></foreignObject>')
```

2) When I put a form element inside the native markup for the element, when I mouse over it, it triggers the `cell:mouseout` event.  Why?  The mouse is still inside the jointjs element?

3) When I mouse over the form element, I cannot click on it and add input to the element even though the cursor changes to the appropriate cursor.  Why does the input element not accept input?

Thanks,
Denise